# Minima of $f(t) = \|z + tu\|^2$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, optimization

This appears in the proof of Theorem 5.24 of Folland's Real Analysis.

Here he is proving the following:

> Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. If $M$ is a closed subspace of $H$, then $H = M \bigoplus M^\perp$; that is each $x \in H$ can be expressed uniquely as $x = y + z$ where $y \in M$ and $z \in M^\perp$. Moreover, $y$ and $z$ are the unique elements of $M$ and $M^\perp$ whose distance to $x$ is minimal.

In the proof he lets $\delta = \inf\{\|x - y\| : y \in M\}$, given $x \in H$. He then shows that $y \in M$ and $\|x - y \| = \delta$. This part of the proof makes sense to me, so I will not include it here.

He then sets $z = x- y$, and shows that $z \in M^\perp$. He begins by saying if $u \in M$, after multiplying $u$ by a nonzero scalar we may assume $\langle z, u \rangle$ is real.

This is the part that confuses me. He introduces the following real quadratic function:

$f(t) = \|z + tu\|^2 = \|z\|^2 + 2t\langle z, u\rangle + t^2 \|u\|^2, \quad t \in \mathbb{R}$

and claims it has a minimum (namely, $\delta^2$) at $t = 0$. His reasoning is that $z + tu = x - (y - tu)$ and $y - tu \in M$. However, doesn't simple algebra show that the minimum occurs at
$$t = -\frac{\langle z, u \rangle}{\|u\|^2}.$$

So how does it follow that $t = 0$ if we do not know a priori that $\langle z, u \rangle = 0$? I am sure there is some geometric argument I am overlooking.

My best guess is that since $z + tu = x - (y - tu)$, $\|z + tu\| \geq \delta$, by definition of $\delta$. So it is clear that the minima is indeed $\delta^2$. Does it then follow that $t = 0$ because he showed earlier that $\|x - y\| = \delta$?

Comment: In the second paragraph, you go from talking about $$u$$ to talking about $$\left<z, y \right>$$. How are they related?

Comment: @AJY That is a typo sorry, I have edited the question.

Comment: You say “He then… shows $z \in M^perp$.” Is the part you’re stuck on *how* he shows that $z \in M^\perp$?

Comment: @AJY Yes that is correct, I am trying to understand how he shows that $z \in M^\perp$. If the minima of the function in my question occurs at $t = 0$, then the result follows because $f'(0) = 2\langle z, u\rangle = 0$, and so $z \in M^\perp$.

Comment: Understood, leaving a new answer.

Comment: Your "best guess" is right on track.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We said before that $\|x-y\| = \delta = \inf \{ \|x - w \| : w \in M \}$. Since $y - t u \in M$, it follows that $$\| z + t u \| = \| x - (y - t u) \| \geq \inf \{ \|x - w \| : w \in M \} = \| z + 0 u \|.$$

Does that clear it up?

Comment: Yes that does, thank you very much!

Comment: **Remark:** $\|z + tu\| \ge \|z\|$ for every $t\in \Bbb R$ indeed shows that $t = 0$ is a point of minima, but I believe it *may not be the only minima*. Regardless, we don't need that to complete the proof. Since $f$ is smooth in $t$, and $t = 0$ is a minima (possibly just one of many), we have $f'(0) = 0$ and the result follows.

Comment: @heroic-harmonic The quadratic description in the OP tells us the minimum is unique.

Comment: @AJY Good point, my bad!